# How to structure cmake project with 2 main src files

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to understand how to structure my cpp project correctly.  I am using the build generator CMAKE.  The build system I am using is Ninja.  I have 2 main functions in my project.  Each main should be compiled into a different executable.

When and why should I use multiple cmake files?
How can I better structure my project?

```
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- README.md
    |-- env.csh
    |-- include
    |   |-- Pen.h
    |   |-- Cup.h
    |   |-- Clip.h
    |   |-- Fun.h
    |   |-- Ins.h
    |   |-- Ne.h
    |   `-- Pa.h
    |-- libs
    |-- src
    |   |-- Pen.cpp
    |   |-- Cup.cpp
    |   |-- Clip.cpp
    |   |-- Fun.cpp
    |   |-- Ins.cpp
    |   |-- Ne.cpp
    |   |-- Pa.cpp
    |   |-- main0.cpp
    |   `-- main1.cpp
    `-- tests
        `-- test.cpp
```

Comment: Do you have a CMake file that you are trying to compose? Your question is largely open-ended as there is no *correct* way to structure the project. It is up to your engineering judgement, and typically depends on the complexity of the file structure and third-party library dependencies. Your example is fairly simple so one CMake file could easily suffice...

Comment: What would the general CMake structure be if main0 and main1 share the same lib files?

Comment: Like I said, for the example you've provided, there doesn't seem to be a need to make more than one CMake file. But again, that is my opinion, and only based on the details you've provided. This question feels more suitable for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one `add_executable()` line for each executable in your project. Try this `CMakeLists.txt` file (written mostly from memory):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(myproject LANGUAGES CXX)
enable_testing()
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
set(SOURCES 
    src/Pen.cpp 
    src/Cup.cpp  
    src/Clip.cpp  
    src/Fun.cpp  
    src/Ins.cpp  
    src/Ne.cpp  
    src/Pa.cpp
)
add_executable(main0 src/main0.cpp ${SOURCES})
add_executable(main1 src/main1.cpp ${SOURCES})
add_executable(unittests tests/test.cpp ${SOURCES})
add_test(tests unittests)
```

Comment: thanks for the edit, @squareskittles ! As I said, this was made from memory, and I expected there to be typos :-)